# How to write into an Excel file in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2. I have a requirment -write data into an excel file(I need to pass dynamic variables to same excel file in future.That is, when i am running each time, different set of data should be entered to the excel,so i have used edit-xlsx). I have used below code for that.

```
var EditXlsx = require('edit-xlsx');
var xlsx = new EditXlsx('../files/exl.xlsx');
var sheet = xlsx.sheet(0);
var data = {
title: 'AKIRA'}
sheet.update('A1', 'Title');
```

But when i am running the protractor script,it says  "Error: Cannot find module 'edit-xlsx' ".When i have installed edit-xlsx by the command 'npm install edit-xlsx' it  gives error and its given below(I have also installed python 2.7 successfully).

```
F:\frx-automation>npm install edit-xlsx

> libxmljs@0.9.0 install F:\frx-automation\node_modules\libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild


F:\frx-automation\node_modules\libxmljs>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp- 
bin\\..\..\node_modules\
node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Python37-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd F:\frx-automation\node_modules\libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin@1.7.0 requires a 
peer of protractor@>= 4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@
1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} 
(current{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.9.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.9.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018- 
020T03_43_13_721Z-debug.log
```

Am i going wrong?Thanks in advance

Comment: so, show please error. This module `edit-xlsx` was not installed. You could check it inside the `node_modules` folder

Comment: `npm i edit-xlsx` Try once again it may be some intermittent issue. I used the same command and got the package installed. If you are using vpn try connecting with your own proxy.

Comment: I have tried command, 'npm i edit-xlsx' and i am not using vpn. Still i am not able to install npm i edit-xlsx. I have added the errors above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

edit-xlsx requires python version between 2.5 and 3.0

set npm to point to version 2.7 using below command if not installed then pls install correct version from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

```
npm install --python=python2.7
```

then install edit-xlsx using

```
npm install edit-xlsx
```

Comment: I have installed python2.7 and then edit-xlsx, but still i got error(I have added the errors above, in the question).

Comment: Your python environment variable is set to 2.7 python exe ?
check if you are able to run 
python --version from any directory and what is the output

Comment: @Devleena - I also suggest you can try a new xls plugin, it worked for me

Usage can be seen here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx  

C:\>npm install xlsx
C:\ npm install xlsx
`-- xlsx@0.13.2
  +-- adler-32@1.2.0
  | `-- printj@1.1.2
  +-- cfb@1.0.8
  +-- codepage@1.14.0
  | `-- commander@2.14.1
  +-- commander@2.15.1
  +-- crc-32@1.2.0
  +-- exit-on-epipe@1.0.1
  `-- ssf@0.10.2
    `-- frac@1.1.2

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.